# Perl equivalent of Python's list comprehensions with the embedded if statement?

Tags: python, perl

In python, I can do the following to get all the objects in a list with a specific property. In this example I grab the list of `id` fields of every `obj` in list `objs` where `obj.id` is greater than 100:

```
ids = [ obj.id for obj in objs if obj.id > 100]
```

How would I do the same in perl?  I think I want to use `map`, but I don't know how to conditionally map items from the origin set to the destination set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `map` block can return 0 or more elements for each element in the original list.  To omit an element, just return the empty list `()`:

```
my @ids = map { $_->id > 100 ? $_->id : () } @objs;
```

This assumes that the objects in `@objs` have an `id` attribute and associated accessor.  If you want direct hash access, you can do that too:

```
my @ids = map { $_->{id} > 100 ? $_->{id} : () } @objs;
```

Or, you can just combine `map` and `grep`:

```
my @ids = map { $_->id } grep { $_->id > 100 } @objs;

# Or reverse the order to avoid calling $_->id twice:
my @ids = grep { $_ > 100 } map { $_->id } @objs;
```

I'm not sure which of those would be more efficient, but unless `@objs` is really big, that's unlikely to matter much.

If the value you're extracting from the object is expensive to calculate, then you can cache the value for the test and return value:

```
my @vals = map { my $v = $_->expensive_method;  $v > 100 ? $v : () } @objs;
```

Comment: `map+($_->id)x($_->id>100),@objs`

Comment: @ysth:  Yikes.  I think I'd save that one for code golf.  The ternary operator is much safer, since you don't have to ensure your condition returns only 0 or 1.

Comment: if in doubt, use the `()x!!` operator

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` to return only those items that match the condition.  It's like `filter` in other languages.

`grep` `{ condition }` `@array`

For example:

```
my @nums = (1, 50, 7, 105, 200, 3, 1000);
my @numsover100 = grep { $_ > 100 } @nums;
foreach my $num (@numsover100) {
    print $num . "\n";
}
```

Comment: So I have to pair that with `map` to get what I want? Since I actually want the sub-field of each of the objects that I've `grep`'d out of the list?

Comment: Yep, that's the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get by with combining [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [filter](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=724210), which is essentially what we did in Python before list comprehensions.

Comment: Perl's `filter` equivalent is called `grep`.  No need to go to the lengths they went to in your perlmonks link for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using map and grep together passes over the list twice. Build your own:

```
sub fancy_filter {
  my ($map_block, $grep_block, @list) = @_;
  my @results;
  foreach my $item (@list) {
    local $_ = $item;
    if ($grep_block->()) {
      push @results, $map_block->();
    }
  }
  return @results;
}

my @ids = fancy_filter(
  sub { $_->{id} },       # map block
  sub { $_->{id} > 100 }, # grep block
  @id_list,
)
```